# How to set the color of the disabled button text?

Tags: python, tkinter

There is a button.
How can I set the color of the disabled button text?

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

button = tk.Button(frame, text="X", fg="red")
button.grid(row=0, column=0)
button['state'] = tk.DISABLED

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The button has a `disabledforeground` attribute which defines the color of the text when the widget is disabled.

```
button = tk.Button(..., disabledforeground="white")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. BTW, I was looking for something to change background when it's disabled. I've found that we do not have disabledbackground attribute in tkinter. The background attribute or bg itself is set for normal or disabled buttons and background color won't change to gray when a button is disabled.

Answer (score -1):

```
fg = "red" , bg = "red"
```

add this code it will be work

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Could you show the code please?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for the code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its [long-term value](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by describing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

button = tk.Button(frame, text="X", fg="red",bg="red")
button.grid(row=0, column=0)
button['state'] = tk.DISABLED

root.mainloop()